# Eclipse CDT Debug Has Extra Lines In Scanf

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt, cstdio

I have a simple piece of code that will echo whatever you type into the console:

```
int main(){
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    char c = -1;
    while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1){
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

But when I Debug this code in Eclipse CDT it outputs the following without me typing anything into the console.

```
47-thread-select 1
```

How can I disable this from being fed into the input stream? Also sometimes if I run this there are multiple lines being outputted so I cannot simply discard 1 line.

Comment: Required reading: [C FAQ - `scanf`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Comment: Does this happen when you run or debug your code outside of Eclipse CDT? Do you know where that output is coming from?

Comment: This problem does not occur in Visual Studio for Run or Debug. This only occurs when launching the program using the "Debug <Project Name>" option in Eclipse CDT and does not occur using the "Run <Project Name>" option.

Comment: Under further examination I found that the standard input stream was fighting with the GDB console. The inputs given via a file was causing errors in the GDB console whilst commands in the GDB console is being picked up by scanf.

Comment: What method do you use to get the program to read from a file while debugging in CDT?  Also, which versions of both GDB and CDT are you using?